# VS Code Jenkinsfile docker.withRegistry {...} brackets do not match error

Tags: docker, jenkins, visual-studio-code, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a jenkinsfile in VS Code and when I use `docker.withRegistry("some.registry"){...}` I get a brackets do not match error inside of code. It parses fine inside jenkins, but this error inside of code is bugging me a lot. As soon as anything goes between the `{}` I get the error show up on the closing bracket.

Even copying in directly from the documentation from the Jenkins website gives the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your jenkinsfile for better understanding problem

Comment: I get this issue when including steps that have asterisks inside single quoted strings such as `archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar'` (note that this also comes from the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)). The IDE warning goes away if I use double quotes but I haven't checked whether behaviour remains the same. It's far from obvious when to use which type of quote but [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4) helps.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough I had the same issue when I was using a private registry with a credentials ID, when I switched away from single quotes to double quotes the error went away, you could give that a try?

```
docker.withRegistry("https://some.registry", "docker-registry-creds") { 
    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.GIT_COMMIT}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Carl here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594055/vs-code-jenkinsfile-docker-withregistry-brackets-do-not-match-error#comment113217799_63594055), this happens when you have the following 2 characters, in this particular order, in a single quoted string:

```
'/*'
```

So strings like the following will trigger the error:

- `'**/*.xml'`
- `'/some/path/to/random/files/*.py'`

Just use double quote in those strings, and all the errors will go away:

- `"**/*.xml"`
- `"/some/path/to/random/files/*.py"`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this also occurs when using a parenthesis in single quotes. Again fixed by putting these in double quotes.
e.g.:

```
def something= somethingelse.tokenize('(')
```

can be replaced by

```
def something= somethingelse.tokenize("(")
```